# Is there any solution to change the style value in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

```html
<div class="meter">
  <span style="width: 13%"></span>
</div>
```

Above is my HTML code.
I am going to change the width value in AngularJS.
Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you looking for https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-style` for this

```
<button type="button"  ng-click="changeStyle()">set width</button>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
```

then change the width of the span dynamically using

```
$scope.changeStyle=function(){
    $scope.myStyle="{width:'20px'}";
}
```

[ng-style reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)